# Heroku rake task uninitialized constant for MongoMapper model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongomapper

I have a tiny rake task which just sticks a new delayed job into the queue. I've inserted a debug line

```
desc 'Start processing new rss feed articles'
    task :process_new_articles => :environment do
    config = RSS_CONFIG
    feeds = config['rss_feeds']

    puts Article.all

    feeds.each do |feed|
       Delayed::Job.enqueue ProcessNewArticlesJob.new(feed, config['settings'])
    end
end
```

It seems to be loading the config info correctly. But I'm getting a "uninitialized constant Article" error upon running the task. Article is a MongoMapper model. I've verified the connection to the database (on MongoLab) works fine.

This all works great locally.

--

What is even more bizarre is that referencing Article.all using "heroku run console" works just fine.

--

The stack trace doesn't show much:

```
2011-12-04T22:33:02+00:00 app[start.1]: rake aborted!
2011-12-04T22:33:02+00:00 app[start.1]: uninitialized constant Article
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem and it is totally weird.

I had accidentally named my Article model file, "Article.rb" with a capital A. This caused Heroku to not pick up on it upon running "rake environment".

Strange and most likely a bug?

Comment: I have the same exact problem currently (as the OP) and this is not the issue for me, my "uninitialized constant" does refer to a class defined with lower case filename.