# uninitialized constant ModelObserver - Rake task on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku, rake

Rake task performs ActiveRecord model operations. I added `ActiveRecord::Base` in the rake task and that works locally, but not on Heroku resulting in this error:

> uninitialized constant BookingObserver

on the line with `ActiveRecord::Base`. If I do not include that line then I cannot use the model at all *(resulting in similar error just for the model not the observer)*.

Comment: Please see this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379079/heroku-rake-task-uninitialized-constant-for-mongomapper-model

Answer (score 5):

Your rake task will need to load the Rails environment before executing ActiveRecord code.

```
# lib/tasks/my_tasks.rake
task :my_task => :environment do
  # Your task here
  # it has access to the Rails environment now
end
```

Also see [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044714/whats-the-environment-task-in-rake) and the [Railscast on custom rake tasks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).

Comment: Was already doing that. It works locally after including "ActiveRecord::Base", required because of this bug in Rails: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/882. So I guess the problem is Heroku and not my code. Will try to contact them.

Answer (score 5):

I was using config.threadsafe! which disables dependency loading (thus not loading the observer, just the model). The solution was to add config.dependency_loading = true if $rails_rake_task to the environment.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but I was able to fix the problem by commenting out `config.threadsafe!`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue by commenting out `config.threadsafe!` in production.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I added this code in the application.rb

`config.autoload_paths += Dir[ Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**/') ]`

just before calling:

`config.active_record.observers = [:user_observer]`

i think because my application, it doesnt automatically discovers the directory of my observers which is under models/observers/